Backend Data not being sent to the frontend
Backend Data not being sent to the frontend.
I tried adding cors, proxy server and error handling in my useEffect
I've tried everything and I've been trying to solve this issue for 5 hours.
server.js
I've omitted  my apikey and place id but i am getting data on the backend
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const app = express();
const path = require('path'); // Include the path module

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html')); // Replace 'public' with your actual folder name
});
app.get('/api/reviews', async (req, res) => {
  const apiKey = 'API_KEY';
  const placeId = 'PLACE_ID';
  const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=${placeId}&key=${apiKey}`;

  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    console.log(response);
    const reviews = response.data.result.reviews;
    res.json(reviews); // Send the reviews as JSON
    console.log(reviews);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching Google reviews:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to fetch reviews' });
  }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
});


do you get any error message in return or something happens when you try to console.log reviews?

Did you get any result from the postman ?

What do you see in the browser network tab? Can you see the requests going out? What do the responses look like? Are errors reported in the browser? You really haven't provided any debugging detail here.
